# Recursive function in C to take 3 to the power of another number

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a recursive function in C to take the value of 3 to the power of another number. For example, if I enter 4, the program will return the value 81. And the following code is the answer for the question. But I can not clearly understand how the code can solve the problem. I mean that when 4 is passed to the function, the first 3 lines in the function body will be ignored, jump straight into the " // This line " . Then how is it from there will the program return the number 81. The function calls itself again with 3 passed? 3*three_power(3) ? I can not clearly understand that. Can someone explain? Sorry because it's a stupid question, I'm new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int three_power(int power);
int main(){
    int a=4;
    int b=9;
    printf("\n3 to the power of %d is %d", a, three_power(a));
    printf("\n3 to the power of %d is %d", b, three_power(b));
    return 0;
}
int three_power(int power){
    if (power < 1){
        return( 1 );
    } else
    return (3* three_power(power-1));  //This line
}
```

Comment: This is what you have seen from debugger? Program is not really jumping the first 3 lines, simply they have been optimized out and the debugger cannot correctly trace them. Try to recompile without optimization before to start the debugging session and you will see even the first three lines...

Comment: `return` is not a function, but a statement. You should not add parenthesis around the result. They are not part of the statment, but the expression and unnecessary.

Comment: "*To understand recursion you need to understand recursion ...*" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it takes the `else` branch on the first way through, which causes the recursive call for `4 - 1` which again takes the `else` branch, and so on down to the base case when `power` is 0 which just returns `1` (since 3<sup>0</sup> is 1).

The full chain is

```
3 * three_power(3) =
3 * (3 * three_power(2)) =
3 * (3 * (3 * three_power(1)) =
3 * (3 * (3 * (3 * three_power(0))) =
3 * (3 * (3 * (3 * (1)))) =
3 * 3 * 3 * 3 = 81
```

It's hard to visualize, but that's it.

You can of course single-step through this in a debugger to get a feeling for it, or just add a `printf("power=%d\n", power);` to the first line of `three_power()`.

Comment: Thank you very much !! I can understand it now. Thank you !!

Comment: @Minh Glad to help. Feel free to accept the answer, of course. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the essence of recursion.

In a mathematical sense, you can define the power of 3^n as 3 * 3^(n - 1), right?  After all 3 to the anything is 3 multiplied times itself that number of times, right?

The recursion simply says that the answer to "What is 3 to the power?"  Well it is 3 times three_power of power minus one.  You need only handle the case when power is 0 and the returned value will be multiplied times 3 by the number of recursive calls made.

This is an excellent learning exercise, but you should prefer pow(3, power) because it is more efficient to calculate this way and you don't risk to exceed the maximum recursive call stack.

Comment: I think that he is just doing this as a way of learning recursion. I do not think that he will actually use it (:-)

Comment: @sabbahillel I agree, but I mention it primarily to prevent professional programmers from seeing this page and thinking it is a good idea to use recursion to find the power of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing the command flow showing each entry and exit for your example. Also the return on the else is a single line else. I will rewrite it showing the correct brackets.

1e. enter with value 4

2e. enter with value 3

3e. enter with value 2

4e. enter with value 1

5e. enter with value 0

5r. return 1

4r. return 3*5r = 3*1 = 3

3r. return 3*4r = 3*3 = 9

2r. retrun 3*3r = 3*9 = 27

1r. return 3*2r = 3*27 = 81

```
int three_power(int power)
{
    if (power < 1)
    {
        return( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        return (3* three_power(power-1));  //This line
    }
}
```

Another way of putting it with a single return is

```
int three_power(int power)
{
    int rtnval;
    if (power < 1)
    {
        rtnval = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        rtnval = 3* three_power(power-1);  //This line
    }
    return rtnval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of recursion, which is similar to the mathematical concept of induction.  For a given input, is invokes itself on a reduced input, then uses that result to produce the desired result.

A good way to understand how the function works is to start with the simplest case, verify that it works, then move on to the next simplest case, etc.

In this example, the simplest case is when `power` is `0`.  In that case, it immediately returns `1`.  So far so good.

Now consider what happens when `power` is `1`.  In this case, it returns `3 * power(0)`.  In other words, it calls itself with a different input, then uses that result to produce a new result.  We have already verified that `power(0)` returns 1.  So in this case, it will return `3 * 1`, which is just `3`.  Again, so far so good.

So what happens when `power` is `2`?  Well, it returns `3 * power(1)`.  This results in multiple nested calls.  We know that `power(1)` will return `3`, so this case will return `9`.  Again, it's doing what we want.

More generally, when `power` is `>= 1`, it recursively calls itself to obtain the result for `power - 1`.  This will in general result in a chain of calls which eventually return the desired result for `power - 1`.  It then multiplies this by `3` and returns the result.  This is `3 * (3 ** (power - 1))`, which is just `3 ** power` as desired.

You can confirm its correctness inductively.  The basis case is when `power` is `0`.  This case is confirmed directly.  Then, assuming it gives the correct result for `power - 1`, we can see that it will also give the correct result for `power`, from the recursive step.  It will only fail if the result becomes large enough to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a more efficient recursion than `f(n)=3*f(n-1)`.

It would be

```
// f(n) = 1 if n = 0
// f(n) = f(n/2)^2` if n is even
// f(n) = 3*f(n/2)^2 if n is odd

int power3(int n)
{
    int m;
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        m = power3(n/2);
        return m*m;
    }
    else
    {
        m = power3(n/2);
        return 3*m*m;
    }
}
```

This way the time complexity is reducing from `O(n)` to `O(log(n))`.